# SQLite - Reference to another database table

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have two databases (so also two files) `db1` and `db2`. In `db1` I have a table `foo` and and a column `c1`. In `db2` there is a table `bar` with the primary key `p`. I want to reference `c1` to `p`, so referencing a value between various databases. So I thought it could be possible to do something like

```
create table foo(
    c1 references db2.bar (p)
);
```

But this not work. Is there any way to do this in sqlite?

Comment: The databases have to share a common connection for this to work, and they don't?

Comment: I imported the two databases into my session with attach...

Comment: A foreign key constraint cannot cross databases. But what is the actual problem you're trying to solve; what do you want to *do*?

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand. I want to reference a primary key from another database.